# Is PolymerDart dead? An architecture issue

Tags: dart, polymer, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer, angular-dart

Given the information at both the Polymer and Dart conferences in the last week, there is no information mentioned about the intersection of polymer and dart called PolymerDart at neither of them (except a passing wave, 2 word statement in 1 slide at the dart conference after watching the conference a second time).  Given the last commit for it has been in July, only adding some tests for PolymerDart I am leaning towards yes.

I have been looking into a variety of other sources and it seems that while Polymer and Dart are separately going to continue on their own things respectively, there is no support any longer for the union.   Polymer is focused entirely on PolymerJs and web component standards, where as Dart is pushing deep into AngularDart and its associated architecture.  It seems that after looking deeper into it, the Googlers who were managing this union was in fact a side project, which does not actually have set resources, so there isnt a defined team in place for PolymerDart compatibility.

Given this information and the fact that Google regularly releases a lot of things, some thrive and some die all the time.  They let the community determine it, and is shown over and over again throughout their many projects.

Has anyone else obtained any information related deeper into this?  All my signs are pointing to it being dead.  That said, maybe i should be looking to migrate my team from this and more towards angulardart.

I did as best as I could to only make note of facts and not opinions of any sort, as my opinions are not on trial, the continued development in a fast paced technology where stagnant codebases imply a dead-in-the-water technology.

Comment: It seems they are waiting for DDC to become available to target Polymer 2.0. Polymer Dart 1.0 is rather stale.

Comment: I interpret the brief statement in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXcNqXbCa0E as the Dart Polymer wrapper is abandoned. The inactivity on the github repo backs this. As Günter mentions above the DDC dev environment and js Polymer 2.0 with ES6, seems as a good match, but nothing stated.

Answer (score 1):

After watching the talks it seems to me that the focus is more on making angular2 dart, the angular 2 dart components and the dev compiler more stable and robust.

It's eventually not dead at the moment, but priorities might have shifted.

Thus, you might want to give https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymerize a try.

Comment: polymerize is an individual's attempt to continue the work.  I was looking at this earlier.  I am not unopposed to others picking up the mantel and continuing but in the eyes of Google, it looks abandoned.  The issue is that this build is very volatile and experimental it seems, so it isnt something i would want in production code.